# Inconsistent behavior from 'find' on zfs under Linux

Tags: linux, find, zfs, inode

I was checking to see if I had multiple copies of python on my system today, and I got some super strange behavior from `find`:

```bash
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ ls -i /bin/python3.10
534638 /bin/python3.10
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ ls -i /usr/bin/python3.10
534638 /usr/bin/python3.10
```

As you can see, the two paths have the same inode. Running `find /usr/bin ...` produces the expected results:

```bash
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ find /usr/bin -samefile /bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ find /usr/bin -inum 534638
/usr/bin/python3.10
```

But running `find /bin ...` produces no results:

```bash
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ find /bin -samefile /usr/bin/python3.10
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ find /bin -inum 534638
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$
```

I ran a bunch of Solaris servers back in the day, but this is my first time using zfs under Linux. I let the Ubuntu installer do its thing, and the results are a lot busier than I'd expect—`/etc/mtab` is 89 lines long! So I'm tempted to assume that's where the problem is.

```bash
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ zfs list -t all

NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
...
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_8me7yq                          12.1G   169G     5.45G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_8me7yq/srv                        96K   169G       96K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_8me7yq/usr                       224K   169G       96K  /usr
```

As you can see, `zfs list` shows `/bin` and `/usr/bin` on different mountpoints (`/` and `/usr`, respectively). If so, that could account for *unexpected* behavior from `find` (though it still doesn't really account for *inconsistent* behavior). But not so fast! More WTFery:

```bash
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ zfs get mountpoint /bin/python3.10
NAME                      PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_8me7yq  mountpoint  /           local
mark@neverland:~/repos/lpod-python$ zfs get mountpoint /usr/bin/python3.10
NAME                      PROPERTY    VALUE       SOURCE
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_8me7yq  mountpoint  /           local
```

I don't even know how to start troubleshooting this. Why is my computer gaslighting me?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /bin is most likely a symbolic link to /usr/bin (as is becoming common on Linux distributions, and I believe used to be the case in Solaris since SunOS 4), but 'find' does not follow symlinks that are specified directly in the command line – it does not descend into the target directory at all, so your filters are never compared against /bin/python3.10:

```
$ find /bin
/bin
$
```

```
$ find /bin -ls
 28508001    4 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root       7 Oct 19 00:01 /bin -> usr/bin
$
```

...unless the `-H` option is given:

```
$ find -H /bin -ls
  2883593   72 drwxr-xr-x   5 root  root   69632 Nov 14 14:24 /bin
  2898531   28 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root  root   26536 Nov  1 14:46 /bin/ktutil
  2900363   84 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root  root   84320 Aug 30 00:49 /bin/pinentry-gtk-2
  2902165    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root      17 Jul 25 17:16 /bin/ip6tables-save -> xtables-nft-multi
  2906823    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root      13 Nov  7 15:20 /bin/mysqlcheck -> mariadb-check
  2901613  324 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root  root  328608 Oct 14 14:01 /bin/gpg-agent
  2901954   16 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root  root   14280 Oct  7 20:28 /bin/dbus-run-session
[...]
```

It's easy to find symlinks in a path using `namei`:

```
$ namei -l /bin/python3.10
f: /bin/python3.10
drwxr-xr-x root root /
lrwxrwxrwx root root bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x root root   usr
drwxr-xr-x root root   bin
-rwxr-xr-x root root python3.10
```

But only the *last* component of a path given to 'find' matters here – intermediate symlinks are always followed. (Basically, what matters is the lstat() result on the path.)

---

Use `findmnt` to list all mounts on Linux in an easier-to-read way. A lot of them will probably be either Ubuntu's "ZSys" ZFS integration thing or Ubuntu's "Snap" app-container thing (which distributes software in loop-mounted filesystem images); some of them will be kernel filesystems such as /sys. (/etc/mtab is also a symlink to a file in /proc, so it includes every single filesystem mounted, even if it previously might have skipped some "uninteresting" filesystems back when it used to be a regular file.)

Comment: Right you are! It never would have occurred to me that they got rid of  `/bin`... I keep forgetting the FHS is a "trailing standard," i.e. honored in the breach. ;-)  <br/>
  
/dons pointy red cap and skulks back to the garden